# Unable to Group SQL Statement and Calculate Return Rate

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my current table:

```
first_date  any_date    id
2018-12-01  2018-12-01  1234
2018-12-01  2018-12-01  1234
2018-12-01  2018-12-02  1234
2018-12-01  2018-12-01  2434
2018-12-02  2018-12-02  1111
```

My query with MS SQL Server 2017 so far looks like this:

```
select
min(any_date) over (PARTITION by id) AS first_time,
any_date,
id
from sales
```

However, I want to aggregate and add a return rate calculation which refers to each unique first_date with each any_date combination. How do I get this?

```
first_date  any_date    count id return_rate
2018-12-01  2018-12-01  2        100% (because this is the cohort start)
2018-12-01  2018-12-02  1        50%
2018-12-02  2018-12-02  1        100%
```

Comment: What is `count id`? How is `return_rate` calculated?

Comment: It looks like count is the number of items in each "group" where group is the distinct combination of first_date, any_date and id.  I have no idea why id doesn't have a value in his expected result.  His comment about the return rate implies to me that it should be 100% when any_date = first_date and 50% otherwise but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Samcd Return rate is calculated as: #unique id's on nth day/ #unique id first day for reach unique first day cohort start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could aggregate by `first_date` and `any_date`, and then use window function `first_value()` to pull out the count of distinct id of the first day of the cohort:

```
select 
    t.*, 
    1 .0 * count_id 
        / first_value(count_id) over(partition by first_date order by any_date) return_rate
from (
    select first_date, any_date, count(distinct id) count_id
    from sales
    group by first_date, any_date
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fidde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3022bc5d22150a3f6952f3d83c30fb18)**:

```
first_date          | any_date            | count_id | return_rate   
:------------------ | :------------------ | -------: | :-------------
01/12/2018 00:00:00 | 01/12/2018 00:00:00 |        2 | 1.000000000000
01/12/2018 00:00:00 | 02/12/2018 00:00:00 |        1 | 0.500000000000
02/12/2018 00:00:00 | 02/12/2018 00:00:00 |        1 | 1.000000000000
```

Comment: thank you for this. I am trying to understand what you define as "first_value". Can you help please?

Comment: @cocoo84hh:  `first_value(count_id) over(partition by first_date order by any_date)` is the count of distinct ids for the earliest `any_date` that has the same `first_date`. In other words, that's the count of distinct ids for the day the cohort starts.

Comment: I adjusted my query based on your reply which was very helpful. But there is some size error now. Can you see this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f922f6c553daeb378ec65b2ffc393364

Comment: @cocoo84hh: I have no idea what you are trying to do in the fiddle. I can only answer the question that you have asked, which I think I did (if so, then I woud suggest that you accept this answer). If you have more queries, I would suggest opening a *new* question, with relevant sample data, expected results, and explanation of the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select first_date, any_date, count(*) as on_this_date,
       count(*) * 1.0 / max(count(*)) over (partition by first_date) as ratio
from (select distinct first_date, any_date, id
      from t
     ) t
group by first_date, any_date;
```

This assumes that the maximum value is the first value.